# Custom UITableViewCell woes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an iPhone app with a form input screen. I did this by making a custom `UITableViewCell` that has a `UILabel` and a `UITextfield`. I set it up so that the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" fetches the appropriate value from Core Data, and the `UITextField's` "textFieldDidEndEditing" method saves the appropriate value to Core Data. It works great... except:

If I edit a text field, then scroll it off screen, then click on another cell's text field:

1. The cell has been autoreleased because it scrolled off screen
2. The "textFieldDidEndEditing" gets a BAD ACCESS error

I understand the problem completely, I'm just not sure the best way to fix it. My first thought was to add the logic from "textFieldDidEndEditing" to "dealloc", but that seems hacky. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using a delegate method for scroll view (which is built in to the UITableView). When the user starts dragging, I resign first responder.

This works perfectly because it looks nice, and "textFieldDidEndEditing" gets called when the user starts to scroll, which is always before the text field goes off screen.

Comment: For those wondering, the I used the - (void) scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView delegate method

Answer (score 1):

- disable scrolling while editing
- retain your textField

that are the things you could do. In my opinion its best to disable scrolling while editing because the user has no need to, so make sure he also can not do so. Limit the things your user can do, makes it more "secure" for you and easier to use for the user.

If you are not sure about such things just look at what apple does, they are always right in their applications. Like in the settings app on iOS 5, when you change your phone's name. You simply get 1 row in the next tableview so you can't really mess anything up as the user..

Answer (score 0):

In your custom cell's dealloc, set the textfield's delegate to nil

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue... The problem lies in the reusable cells as part of the Table View. Every time the table is scrolled, the cellforRowatIndexPath gets called, and dequeues a cell and returns it. Sadly, this functionality doesnt work well with cells having retainable data such as labels. Hence you must opt for your own method of dequeueing the cell.

I have an NSMutableArray called cells which holds all my cells.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
CustomTableViewCell *cell = [self dequeuwReusableCellwith:indexPath];
if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[CustomTableViewCell alloc] init];
    [cells addObject:cell];
}
// Configure the cell.
NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %d",indexPath.row];
cell.textField.placeholder=temp;
return cell;
}
```

and this is my custom method to deque Reusable cells.

```
-(CustomTableViewCell*)dequeuwReusableCellwith:(NSIndexPath*)indexpath
{
if([cells count]>indexpath.row)
{
    return [cells objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
}
return nil;
}
```

Hope this helps...